# Identify story/book where paralegals are also a paramilitary group

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading this story/book about 5-7 years ago. It was in English. The main thing I remember is that the paralegals, probably for a corporation or some other entity, were also militarized. The one scene I remember is the paralegals dropping in from a helicopter and breaking into a building in order to steal information, or something like that. I think it may have taken place in an alternate reality, but I can't be sure of that. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Please try to add anything that may help identification.  What language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be Eoin Colfer's *[The Supernaturalist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Supernaturalist)*? It does have a scene where a squad of paralegals break into a building, albeit to seize a prototype engine design.

> One night, the Supernaturalists stalk out a drag race, as the potential for fatal crashes, and Parasites, is large. However, one of the cars is a prototype stolen from Myishi Corporation, who track it down and send **a squad of paralegals ("hit lawyers")** to take it back. In the following firefight, Cosmo and Stefan are captured by Myishi. They are taken to Ellen Faustino, the president of Myishi, who reveals herself to be a Spotter. She says that energy discharged by the Parasites is forcing the Satellite into an incorrect orbit and causing it to fall out of the sky. She also reveals that the method the Supernaturalists are using to kill the Parasites is only causing them to reproduce faster, increasing the problem with the Satellite. After some discussion, she reveals that she has a plan to kill the Parasites: detonate an electrical bomb in the Parasite hive that contaminates them and eventually kills them. However, she does not know where the hive is, and sets the Supernaturalists to find the hive.

It was released as both a print and a graphic novel.

Comment: Yes, this was it! Thanks so much!

Comment: :) The scene stuck with me.